# Change the default site loaded when accessing the server via IP

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an apache server with 2 sites on it. When I load the IP of the server, it loads up one site, but I'd like it to load the other. I am not running cpanel or plesk, just a basic redhat box with apache and virtual servers.

I can't seem to recall how I can control what configuration to change in order to change where the IP points to when I access it.

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <VirtualHost> that's first in the list will be the default. So you simply need to move the site you want as default to be the first one in config file.